# Destroy method doesn't redirect to route

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to delete data from comments.index:

```
<a href="{{route('comments.create', ['id'=>$post->id])}}">Create Comment</a>
    @foreach ($comments as $comment)
        @if ($comment->post_id == $post->id)
        <div class="border margin mb-1">
            <div class="border margin">
                <p>{{$comment->text}}</p>
            </div>
            <a href="{{route('comments.edit', $comment->id)}}" class="btn btn-primary float-end">Edit</a>
            <form action="{{ route('comments.destroy', $comment->post_id) }}" method="POST">
                @csrf
                @method('delete')
                <div class="buttons are-small">
                    <input type="submit" class="button is-danger is-rounded" value="Drop Me!"/>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        @endif
    @endforeach
```

The program goes to route:

```
Route::delete('/delete_comments/{id}', [CommentController::class, 'destroy'])->name('comments.destroy');
```

The problem here is that it doesn't get to destroy function and it doesn't redirect back.
In controller I got for destroy method:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    //
    $comment = Comment::FindOrFail($id);
    $comment->delete();
    return redirect()->route('comments.index', ['id'=>$id])->with('message', 'Comment deleted');
}
```

Which should go to route:

```
Route::get('/get_comments/{id}', [CommentController::class, 'showByPost'])->name('comments.index');
```

This has the function:

```
public function showByPost($id){
    $comments = Comment::all();
    $post = Post::FindOrFail($id);
    // dd($user);
    return view('comments.index', ['post'=>$post, 'comments'=>$comments]);
}
```

Comment: You're passing the post_id into the destroy route, then look for that comment's ID. you need to pass in the comment ID to the route. Then reverse it on your redirect: your post_id should be passed into `comments.index`, not the comment ID.

Comment: It worked, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get your data like this:

```
$data = YOUR_MODEL::findOrFail($id);
```

then:

```
    $data->delete();
```

You need to get the $id like what you did up here.

Answer (score 0):

first: you must check you compiled html, see realpath on page for :`action="{{ route('comments.destroy', $comment->post_id) }}"`

second : when you click submit button, you can use chrome to view you post data;

third: check you request url and response data (headers and body)